# How to evaluate strings in variable name

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I evaluate strings in script?

For example

I want to write this code.

```
$('#ul23').prepend(item);
```

But I have number only in variable such as

```
var x = 23;
$('#ul{x}').prepend(item); // how can I make it??I know only the php way...
```

Comment: umm why not just concatenate? like '#ul'+x

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just this:

```
$("#ul" + x).prepend(item);
```

Side note: such syntax exists in [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/). In CoffeeScript you can write `"abc#{x}def"` and it will become `"abc23def"`. Although in JavaScript it will actually be translated to `"abc" + (x) + "def"`.

Comment: concatenation is what we call it

Comment: dang it was so simple :D btw +1 for coffee